# Does testcafe support pressKey("shift+enter")?

Tags: automated-tests, keypress, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am trying to test if pressing the `shift+enter` keys will result in a newline. I've checked the docs and they do not have this combination listed there; will this combination ever be added in or is it already there and I just missed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your editor implementation. If your editor uses a `contenteditable` element inside, then according to the documentation it supports only the following combinations: 'ctrl+a', 'backspace', 'delete', 'left' and 'right' (only if text within the element is selected).

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/press-key.html

However, it should work fine with the `textarea` element.

Comment: Ah, I am using `contenteditable`. Is there any way for me to get the `shift+enter` combination?

Comment: For now, we do not have plans to implement this feature. I've prepared a workaround which emulates the described behavior. 
It works with a simple contenteditable element, but I don't know if it will work in your complex editor. 
 
Please refer to it https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/c8834424f2f078f0942b73eaa18661c7

Comment: Thank you so much again Alex!